# What are all the $A$-invariant subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n\geq 1$.
Let $A$ be an invertible linear map $\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n$.

I would like to recognize all the $A$-invariant subspaces.
So, I consider the Jordan normal form of $A$. Each Jordan block of dimensions $d\times d$ gives a chain of $d$ nested $A$-invariant subspaces. I call these the "basic $A$-invariant subspaces".

Every direct sum of basic $A$-invariant subspaces is $A$-invariant.

> Is every $A$-invariant subspace a direct sum of basic $A$-invariant subspaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, up to the change of coordinates giving the Jordan form (which of course need not be unique) and up to the space $\{0\}$.

And why do you want $A$ to be invertible? It is not needed.

Comment: Can you please provide or sketch a proof?

Comment: Your result is absolutely false when there are two Jordan blocks associated to the same eigenvalue.